# Convert yyyyMMdd to date with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a string variable which stores input as `yyyyMMdd` in in scala while using spark.

```
snapshot_date = 20191001
```

I want to convert this to date first, then subtract a day from this date and will convert again to `yyyyMMdd` format, so my previous date variable will be `20190930`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below approach you can achieve i believe

```scala
 val input_df = List("20190930").toDF("date")
 input_df.withColumn("new_date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date","yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd"),1), "yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyyMMdd")).show
```

```
Output:

+--------+--------+
|    date|new_date|
+--------+--------+
|20190930|20190929|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you Rakshith , This really helped.
I replaced the new date with the date, Now how can I take this date from dataframe and store it in a variable, which latter I will use in my script. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
val df = Seq("20191001").toDF("date")
df.show()
+--------+
|    date|
+--------+
|20191001|
+--------+ 

df.select(date_format(date_sub(to_date('date,"yyyyMMdd"),1),"yyyyMMdd").as("date")).show()

+--------+
|    date|
+--------+
|20190930|
+--------+
```

Comment: The first statement runs fine in CDSW using scala, But the scond one throws below error. 

df.select('date,"yyyyMMdd").show()

Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:69: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1, U2](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1], c2:

Comment: Also If i run the full second statement , this throws below error

df.select(date_format(date_sub(to_date('date,"yyyyMMdd"),1),"yyyyMMdd").as("date")).show()

Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:69: error: too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: you are receiving this error because to_date function with 2 arguments is available in spark > 2.2.0 and looks like you are using older version